# Whatsapp share-link: can I re-use an open web.whatsapp.com browser-tab to send the link to

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, whatsapp

I'm building a site that let's the user share their creation to WhatsApp by means of a WhatsApp share link. In case of desktop-screens I refer to web.whatsapp.com in a new window. But I know lot's of cases Web.whatapp.com is already open, and this would disconnect the open tab and continue in the new one.

Is there a way to check if a browser tab already has a WhatsApp tab open? And append the message to the existing tab?

```html
<li id="wa4" class="wa"><a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=user-generated-text" target="_blank">Whatsapp (web)</a></li>
```